# MapReduce and HDFS Block size

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

In a textbook about Java for Hadoop i read :

**Map tasks in MapReduce normally operate on one block at a time,
so if you have too few tasks (fewer than nodes in the cluster), your jobs will run slower than they could otherwise**

This sentence is in the paragraph about the HDFS Block size, but i dont understand its meaning.
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The number of mappers depends upon the number of input spilit and the number of input spilit is by default will be the number of block size in mapreduce. So in this case , suppose if you have a file size of 128 MB then by default one mapper will be used for computing,  but you can increase the number of mapper by changing some property in mapred-site.xml , Now after Increasing the number of mapper , same 128 MB file will be computed by more mappers and execution will be faster then previous situation.